# SQL query one to many

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have two tables

Table1: Customers

```
+----+-------+--+
| ID | Name  |  |
+----+-------+--+
|  1 | Jhon  |  |
|  2 | Doe   |  |
|  3 | Magi  |  |
+----+-------+--+
```

Table2: Orders

```
+-------------+----------+--------------+
| OrderNumber | ItemName | PurchasedBy  |
+-------------+----------+--------------+
|         111 | Shirt    | 1            |
|         222 | Pant     | 2            |
|         333 | Trouser  | 2            |
|         444 | T-Shirt  | 3            |
|             |          |              |
+-------------+----------+--------------+
```

I need to write a query that will show below table

```
+--------------+----------------+----------------+
| CustomerName | PurchasedItem1 | PurchasedItem2 |
+--------------+----------------+----------------+
| Doe          | Pant           | Trouser        |
| Jhon         | Shirt          | Null           |
| Magi         | T-Shirt        | Null           |
+--------------+----------------+----------------+
```

Anyone can give me a solution? I am new to SQL and trying to learn.

Comment: If you're new to SQL don't get in the habit of showing multiple related items in separate columns.  What if a customer had 3 items?  100?  Have a row for each customer/item combination.  Adding columns dynamically is MUCH easier in the display layer (report, web page, form, etc.) than in SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am new to SQL and trying to learn.

One thing you should learn is not to show multiple related items in separate *columns*.  Adding columns dynamically is not simple in SQL since it's designed to work with static *columns* and multiple *rows*.

I would start with a "standard" query that shows multiple rows per customer/item combination:

```
SELECT 
    c.Name CustomerName, 
    o.ItemName PurchasedItem
FROM Customers c
INNER JOIN Orders o
  ON c.ID = o.PurchasedBy
```

Which would give you the results

```
+--------------+----------------+
| CustomerName | PurchasedItem  |
+--------------+----------------+
| Doe          | Pant           |
| Doe          | Trouser        | 
| Jhon         | Shirt          |
| Magi         | T-Shirt        |
+--------------+----------------+
```

Then leave it to the *display layer* (report, form, web page, etc.) to deal with multiple items per customer.  It is generally MUCH easier to add columns dynamically at that layer that at the data layer.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    c.Name CustomerName, 
    o.ItemName PurchasedItem
FROM Customers c
INNER JOIN Orders o
  ON c.ID = o.PurchasedBy
GROUP BY 1
```

try adding the "Group by 1" .